# How to use FieldPosition argument in java MessageFormat.format method?

Tags: java

How is the FieldPosition argument used in the `MessageFormat.format` method in java?  In all the examples I have seen online, there have been no uses of the FieldPosition argument.  Is this argument used for anything?  I am looking at the spec here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html.  Method signature is copied below.

```
public final StringBuffer format(Object[] arguments,
                                 StringBuffer result,
                                 FieldPosition pos)
```

Answer (score 3):

**FieldPosition** keeps track of the position of the field within the formatted output with two  indices: the index of the first character of the field and the index of the last character of  the field.

You can use like

```
  NumberFormat numForm = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    StringBuffer dest1 = new StringBuffer();
    FieldPosition pos = new FieldPosition(NumberFormat.INTEGER_FIELD);
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(22.3423D);
    dest1 = numForm.format(bd1, dest1, pos);
    System.out.println("dest1 = " + dest1);
    System.out.println("INTEGER portion is at: " + pos.getBeginIndex() +
        ", " + pos.getEndIndex());
    pos = new FieldPosition(NumberFormat.FRACTION_FIELD);
    dest1 = numForm.format(bd1, dest1, pos);
    System.out.println("FRACTION portion is at: " + pos.getBeginIndex() +
            ", " + pos.getEndIndex());
```

Output

```
 dest1 = 22.342
 INTEGER portion is at: 0, 2
 FRACTION portion is at: 9, 12
```

For DateFormat

```
 FieldPosition pos = new FieldPosition(DateFormat.YEAR_FIELD);
 FieldPosition pos2 = new FieldPosition(DateFormat.MONTH_FIELD);
```

**About FieldPosition argument used in the MessageFormat.format**

```
// Create a pattern for our MessageFormat object to use.
    String pattern = "he bought {0,number,#} "
            + "apples for {1,number,currency} " + "on    {2,date,MM/dd/yyyy}.";
    String pattern2 = "I bought {0} " + "apples for {1} " + "on {2}.";
    // Create values to populate the position in the pattern.
    Object[] values = { 5, 7.53, new Date() };
    // Create a MessageFormat object and apply the pattern
    // to it.
    MessageFormat mFmt = new MessageFormat(pattern);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("Wow,");
    System.out.println(mFmt.format(values, buf, null));
```

Comment: Was this your complete post?  In your lowest example, it looks like you're response was cut off.  Should the example involve a case where the third argument of mFmt.format(values, buf, null) is not null?  Since that is the FieldPosition argument and is what my question is asking.

Comment: Are you use `FRACTION portion is at: 9, 12`?  I was trying to follow your example, but shouldn't it be `FRACTION portion is at: 3, 6` or some such?